# Java arrays, getting the first word from an array of strings alphabetically

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The issue I am having is regarding a lab work question at uni, so all I'd like is a little bit of guidance on where to go from here. The question is giving a code snippet, and from that we should get the first and last elements of the array, alphabetically:

```
public class NamesTest {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    // values hard-coded to facilitate testing
    String[] names = {"john", "mary", "andy", "beth", "chris",
                      "frank", "carol", "bob", "sue", "joe"};     
    System.out.println("first: " + getFirstAlphabetically(names));
    System.out.println("last: " + getLastAlphabetically(names));      
  }
}
```

Expected output:

> first: andy
>   last: sue

Comment: `String firstAlphabetically = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(names));`.

Comment: Do you know about `Comparable`? `Comparator`? `Arrays.sort`? **What are the constraints**? There is the single line answer for Java developers (see [Andy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876189/java-arrays-getting-the-first-word-from-an-array-of-strings-alphabetically#comment67039055_39876189)) and there's the 50 line answer for students not yet using any JDK functionality. Just asking for help without giving us your level/expectations is supremely unhelpful.

Comment: Hi welcome. Since they are plain Strings, you can use [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object[])) to sort the `names`-array, and then get the first item from it.

Comment: Out of the three there, we have used comparable, I have only seen the others online but i don't believe we have went through the other two.

Comment: Apologies for that Boris, this is my first time asking a question about coding on a site.  I am unsure on how to go about it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider thanks for explanation. Didn't know about double space mark. Anyway, if you had problem with my edit what would you say to the current one? It's done just for `refiner badge.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String` implements `Comparable<String>`, where the ordering is lexicographic order (approximately alphabetic, but handles more than just alphabetic characters).

As such:

```
Collections.min(collectionOfStrings)
```

will return the lexicographically-first string in a collection.

But you have an array: you can convert it to a `List` (which is a `Collection`) using `Arrays.asList(arrayOfStrings)`.

Putting it together:

```
String firstAlphabetically = Collections.min(Arrays.asList(names));
```

Similarly, you can use `Collections.max` to get the last string alphabetically.

---

You can also do it without `Collections` or sorting:

```
String firstAlphabetically = names[0];
for (String name : names) {
  if (name.compareTo(firstAlphabetically) < 0) {
    firstAlphabetically = name;
  }
}
```

This runs in `O(n)` time and doesn't change the input, whereas sorting is `O(n log n)`, and either requires you to copy or change the input array.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Arrays.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) to sort your String-array `names`, and then get the first item.

Something like this:

```
String[] names = {"john", "mary", "andy", "beth", "chris",
                  "frank", "carol", "bob", "sue", "joe"};     
Arrays.sort(names);
String alphabeticallyFirst = names[0];
String alphabeticallyLast = names[names.length - 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is an entry level course. Based on this assumption I think the approach they are aiming for is for you to sort the array yourself, then grab the first and last index of the sorted array. If you can't use built in Java libraries look into implementing an algorithm like bubble sort to order the array. Note you can compare two Strings using the CompareTo method.

Comment: It does seem that way, but we haven't actually gotten to bubble sorts yet, that's later in the module, I am in year 2 at university and haven't practised java in a while, so as it stands I am rusty.

Comment: Have you used the String CompareTo method? You don't necessarily need to implement bubble sort exactly. I think you just need to find a way to sort the array using CompareTo (implementing bubble sort would be an easy way to do this).

Comment: Yes, that will probably be what he wants from us.

Comment: Here's a post detailing implementing bubble sort: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644858/bubblesort-implementation

Comment: Actually, what I meant was, he probably wants the CompareTo method from us, because bubble sorting will come later on in the module.  For CompareTo, would i have to make a new class?